# Problem applying @cat in Makefile (Windows)

Tags: c, windows, makefile

I am trying to compile some hardware sensor firmware using the 'make' command and i am getting

```
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
```

First it was because of this

```
rm -rf $(BIN_PATH) $(OBJ_PATH)
```

it could not find rm, which as I understand it, does not work on windows. so i did

```
rd /s /q  $(BIN_PATH) $(OBJ_PATH)
```

Now i have another problem.

```
$(BIN_PATH)/$(SIZE_OUTPUT):
@echo 'Building target: $(SIZE_OUTPUT)'
@echo 'Invoking: Cross ARM GNU Print Size'
$(SIZE_TOOL) --format=berkeley "$(BIN_PATH)/$(ELF_OUTPUT)" > $@
@cat $@
@echo 'Finished building: $(SIZE_OUTPUT)'
@echo ' '

bin: $(BIN_PATH)/$(ELF_OUTPUT) $(BIN_PATH)/$(BIN_OUTPUT) $(BIN_PATH)/$(SIZE_OUTPUT)
```

This is almost the end of the makefile (before the other targets clean, dir and prog).

I am getting an error on the cat

```
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, cat bin/sensit.siz, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make: *** [bin/sensit.siz] Error 2
```

Thoughts?

Comment: There is no `cat` command on Windows unless you have the GNU tools installed

Comment: i installed this: https://developer.arm.com/open-source/gnu-toolchain/gnu-rm/downloads

Comment: is it in your `%path%` when you use the makefile? (you can verify this by typing `where cat` at the command line)

Comment: i installed the gnu tools and added the bin path to the system variables

Comment: Basically, if you can run the command from your prompt then make should be able to run it too.  If you can't, make can't.  So if you type `cat somefile` and it works, then it should work in make.  If it doesn't, you have to fix that before you can expect it to work in make.

Comment: i was using powershell. where cat
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).

This is what i got. so this means i need to look into my gnu installation?

Comment: am i correct about system variables?

Comment: @DottoreM Yes, if `where` says it can't find `cat`, then the makefile in that environment won't find it either

Comment: please structure these comments in an answer -> i will mark it as correct.